# qlikview - count based on a count condition

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have the following table.

| order_number |
| --- |
| 100 |
| 101 |
| 101 |
| 102 |
| 103 |
| 103 |
| 103 |
| 104 |
| 104 |

I'd like to create an expression which counts instances where order_number occurs only once.
Example - 100 and 102 do not repeat, while 101, 103 and 104 have multiple instances.
The expected result is 2.

I've tried
count({<count(order_number)={1}>}order_number)
but does not seem to work.

Tried using Aggr too
count(({<Aggr(count(order_number), order_number))={1}>}order_number)

Comment: And the dimension is `order_number` itself?

Comment: @StefanStoichev Yes, that is correct. Have only one column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Probably not very efficient way)

`sum( if( aggr( count( order_number ), order_number) = 1, 1, 0 ) )`

(from inside to outside)

- `aggr( count( order_number ), order_number)` - will `count` the instances of each `order_number`
- `if( ...  = 1, 1, 0)` - for each `order_number` if the inner (`count`) calculation is equal to 1 then return `1` else `0`
- and `sum(...)` all of this

And the result (in the textbox)

[image: result]

If possible (depends on your requirement) flag these records in the script. After that the expression will be much simple (and efficient)